# Files corrupted by gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

We are currently using gitlab for version control.
Within our project there are a few ressources such as font files (font awesome) and word files (docx).

We noted, that after pushing such files to gitlab and pulling them, they seem to be corrupted. The word files cannot be open as well as the font awesome files are not usable.

Is this a known problem with git? Is there any way to avoid such corruptions?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'corrputed' ? What do you think gitlab has done to your files?

Comment: Try [telling Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files) that those files are binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git will guess when it's checking out (and committing) items to the repository whether a file is text or binary. If it's text, it may perform newline replacements (`\r\n` to `\n` and vice versa) when it commits in, depending on the value of the `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf`. If you want to make sure, use a `.gitattributes` file to tell Git what type of file to expect; for example

```
*.docx binary
*.font binary
```

Then (for subsequent commits only) files with those extensions won't be changed.